# How to parse MongoDB document string in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there a way to parse a user-entered MongoDB document (a string) into a mongodb/Mongoose document which can be inserted to database?

Example **string**

```
'{ "name": "Dave", "location_id" : ObjectId("5d8664a9b1b0ae25d60e0e42") }'
```

Comment: Why are your users entering JS renderings of hashes? Whereever they are getting this format of data from, have *that* end produce valid extended json.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done by utilising `JSON.parse()`, unfortunately, if that data you're passing does have an `ObjectId()` as the example string in your question does this will fail as it's invalid JSON.

Assuming your example string is wrong and you're not trying to pass in an object id you can do it this way:

```js
...
const client = await mongodb.connect("connection-string");
const doc = JSON.parse('{ "name": "Dave", "location_id" : "5d8664a9b1b0ae25d60e0e42" }');

await client.db("my-db").collection("my-data").insertOne(doc);
...
```

If you are passing in invalid JSON such as the `ObjectId` then you will need to perform steps to remove it and pass in it's value as a string, and then add the `location_id` property manually before inserting:

```js
...
doc.location_id = new mongodb.ObjectID(doc.location_id);
...
```